# VB6 ADODB subsequent SELECT queries timeout after moving from SQL2000 to SQL2008

Tags: sql-server, vb6, timeout, migration, adodb

I'm facing timeout issues when performing multiple SELECTs after moving database to a different server, in a relic (VB6 application) I've been tasked to patch up. Things worked flawlessly in the old environemnt, the new one contains carbon copies of the old tables.

**NOTE!** The *new* database was built *from scratch* (that is, DBA ran many CREATE TABLE + INSERT scripts to create carbon copies of tables then fill them with the old data).

This is the error source:

```
// "conn" is being initialized outside the function
Public Function PerformOperation(ByRef conn as ADODB.Connection, query as string) as Boolean
  Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
  //This below is the timeout source
  rs.Open conn, query, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

  If Not (rs.EOF or rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    //assign data to many variables
  End If

ExitPoint:
  If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
    If (rs.State = adStateOpen) Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
  End If   

  Exit Function

Error:
  MsgBox "Blah blah"
  Resume ExitPoint
  Resume 0

End Function
```

Function is called like this

```
conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "..."
conn.Open

For i = 1 To RowCount //reading data from a grid component (data is correct!)
  //very long select here... kept short
  query = "SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE <manyFields> = <manyValues>" 
  If PerformOperation(conn, query) = True Then
    //UPDATE another table based on the SELECT data
    // NOTE: this occurs on a DIFFERENT, INDEPENDENT ADODB.Connection object
  End If
Next i
```

The first time `PerformOperation` is called it goes through fine, second time through it times out no matter how long i set the `CommandTimeout`. It also works OK if the cycle "cycles" a single time.

Big problem here is, all I have to try things out is the **production** environment so I'll need to be extra careful. I also don't have a very deep DBA knowledge at hand... Just a very very old piece of software which will eventually be ported to .NET but needs to be dealt with in the meantime...

How can I check and/or fix this issue ? This **has to** work for any length of the `For` cycle

Many thanks for any suggestion (as always, if i missed any essential detail point it out and i'll provide it if i can).

**EDIT #1**
I've expanded the first and secondo code blocks to provide deeper details about what's going on. Comments changed in order to try and fix highlighting (single quotes mess up coloring).

**EDIT #2**
Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) in the connection string didn't help either.

Comment: Did you update statistics or recreate your indexes after migrating to SQL2008?  If not, you should.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The system's DBA tells me the new database has been created via CREATE TABLE scripts along with massive INSERTs. Nothing has been "migrated" except for the actual data (indexes and everything else should have been rebuilt from scratch, if I'm not mistaken). I'm editing my question to point this fact out.

Comment: Tried destroying and recreating the ADODB.Connection object before every call to the function, timeout still happens :\ starting to think about converting this to a single, bulk select then cycling over the results....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved editing this line:

```
If PerformOperation(conn, query) = True Then
```

like this

```
If PerformOperation(connOther, query) = True Then
```

Basically, method call has been moved to its own connection, declared exactly like the other one. Now it works, though I don't really know why: this is the result of some wild editing in an attempt to patch things up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit suprised that it has worked so well so far.

You have to close the recordset that you open, otherwise you will use up one database connection for each query you run. The database will reclaim the unused connections after a while, but if you use up too many connections too fast you will reach the limit for the number of connections per user, and the database will refuse any more connections.

The reason that it worked at all with the older database is probably because it created new connections as needed. This has been changed in later versions, and you would have to change the settings to allow the older, more resource wasteful behaviour. Changing that setting is however not a good solution to the problem.

Close the recordset and remove the reference when you don't need it any more. That will free up the connection so that you can use it for another query:

```
Public Function PerformOperation(ByRef conn as ADODB.Connection, query as string) as Boolean
  Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
  'This below is the timeout source
  rs.Open conn, query, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

  rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing

  ' [cut]: PerformOperation returns true if SELECT returns something
End Function
```

---

#### Edit:

There are other open states than `adStateOpen`, you should probably check against the closed state instead:

```
If (rs.State <> adStateClosed) Then rs.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I went and checked the function code and it looks like the RecordSet is in fact being disposed of as you suggest. I'm editing my question to include more code.

Comment: @alex: That looks better. I added something more to check out.

Comment: Switching the `if` condition and trying right now... Unfortunately, the timeout still happens. It's **REALLY** strange though, the app is performing a *LOT* of queries all around several databases without an itch. Do you happen to know if/where the timeout can be inspected SQLserver-side ? Something like a "failed queries" log ?